# netlink_kernel_create is not working with latest linux kernel

Tags: c, kernel, netlink

I am getting compiler error while compiling my old `kernel` module which is using netlink functions.

```
int
init_module()
{
    /* Initialize the Netlink kernel interface */
    nl_sk = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, 17, 0, recv_cmd, NULL, THIS_MODULE);
    if(!nl_sk)
    {
            printk(KERN_INFO "failed to initialize system (error: 1001)\n");
            return -ENOMEM;
    }
 ....
```

Previously it works fine but now I am getting this error.

```
error: too many arguments to function 'netlink_kernel_create'
```

OS Information

```
uname -a

Linux ibrar-ahmed 3.8.0-17-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Sun Apr 7 19:39:35 UTC 2013 x86_64  x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just replace

```
nl_sk = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, 17, 0, recv_cmd, NULL, THIS_MODULE);
```

with the following

```
struct netlink_kernel_cfg cfg = {
    .input = recv_cmd,
};

nl_sk = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, 17, &cfg);
```

and it should work. I ran into the same problems.

Answer (score 6):

That's because in 3.8 the netlink_kernel_create prototype has been changed:

netlink_kernel_create(struct net *net, int unit, struct netlink_kernel_cfg *cfg)

(and q.v. http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8/include/linux/netlink.h#L48)

You've no option but to rewrite the kernel module, and remove that extra argument (THIS_MODULE), as well as implement the netlink_kernel_cfg struct.

Comment: Is there any example available?

Comment: With such a new kernel, probably not. Though it should be a fairly straightforward process to modify your implementation to accommodate for the newer APIs. Unfortunately, this is something we've had to deal with in the past, as well (as Linux kernel APIs are evolving, and often quite unstable)

Answer (score 0):

```
    netlink_kernel_create(struct net *net, int unit, struct netlink_kernel_cfg *cfg)

    struct netlink_kernel_cfg cfg = {
        .groups = SELNLGRP_MAX,
        .flags  = NL_CFG_F_NONROOT_RECV,
    };

    selnl = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, NETLINK_SELINUX, &cfg);
    if (selnl == NULL)
        panic("SELinux:  Cannot create netlink socket.");
```